# merging multiple data frames in the global environment to one file

Tags: r, merge

I have 4 dataframes in my global environment. They are named propens1, propens2, propens3 and propens4. I have a 5th file, that is named "bmi" and I want to merge bmi with all of the four propen files. I can merge them individually using dplyr joins or base merge, but I was wondering if there was a way to merge it with a single statement instead of 4.

This is what I have tried, but it doesn't work? Any suggestion is welcomed and appreciated.

```
flist=ls(pattern="propen")
sapply(flist,function(x){merge(x,bmi,by="cfact",all.x=T)})
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have multiple related data frames, it is best to have them all in a list instead of having them all separate in the global environment.  Based on your statement

> They are named propens1, propens2, propens3 and propens4

we can gather all your data frames with

```
datalist <- mget(ls(pattern = "propens[1-4]"))
```

Then since you want four data frames in the result, all we have to do is run `merge()` on each one of those.  Now that we have the data frames in a list, we can do that easily with `lapply()`.

```
lapply(datalist, merge, y = bmi, by = "cfact", all.x = TRUE)
```